# Как правильно создать интерфейс для контейнера dig?

Tags: golang

хочу абстрагироваться от реализации сервис контейнера

```
import (
    "go.uber.org/dig"
)

type Application struct {
    container Container
}

func (app *Application) Run() {
    err := app.container.Invoke(func(config Config) {
        fmt.Println(config.GetHost())
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

type Container interface {
    Provide(constructor interface{}, opts ...interface{}) error
    Invoke(function interface{}, opts ...interface{}) error
}

func NewApplication(container Container) (*Application, error) {
    return &Application{
        container: container,
    }, nil
}

func BuildContainer() (*dig.Container, error) {
    container := dig.New()

    err := container.Provide(interface{}(NewConfig()))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return container, nil
}

func main() {
    container, err := BuildContainer()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    app, err := NewApplication(container)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    app.Run()
}
```

но выпадает ошибка:

```
#13 0.387 cmd/app/main.go:26:40: cannot use container (type *dig.Container) as type application.Container in argument to application.NewApplication:
#13 0.387       *dig.Container does not implement application.Container (wrong type for Invoke method)
#13 0.387               have Invoke(interface {}, ...dig.InvokeOption) error
#13 0.387               want Invoke(interface {}, ...interface {}) error
```

как правильно определить интерфейс?

Answer (score 0):

потому что `dig.Container` реализут другой интрефейс, чем вы ожидаете.

замените ваш интерфейс на

```
type Container interface {
    Provide(constructor interface{}, opts ...dig.ProvideOption) error
    Invoke(function interface{}, opts ...dig.InvokeOption) error
}
```